# How does rsync identify insertions of size that is not divisible by block size?

Tags: algorithm, rsync

I'm trying to understand how rsync algorithm sends only changed parts of the file. Here's the situation I can't understand:

Consider this example, where A is the sender's version of file and B is the reciever's.

```
A = 1111122233333....
B = 1111133333....
```

Let's select 5 bytes as block size for the sake of example.

As you can see, only change is that three 2s were inserted inside A's file.

My understanding is that after correctly determining that 1st block is the same for both files, rsync sees that next blocks are '22233' and '33333', obviously different, proceeds to send that chunk to receiver, and continues in such a way until the end of the file - all blocks would be different due to that insertion, and it will need to send the whole remaining file over the network (possibly gigabytes).

Is there some way for rsync to resolve this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a closer look at [rsync's documentation](http://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html) (the part about The Sender), and here's the explanation (how I understood it):

Rsync uses "rolling checksum", thus it is able to compute accumulated checksum at each byte position.

Thus, in our example, when it read first block (first 5 bytes), it has checksum A<sub>1-5</sub>, which is located in the hash as a block that is present on the receiver - thus 1st block doesn't need to be sent.

Then it proceeds to computing the checksum for the next block (A<sub>6-10</sub>), and doesn't see it in the receiver's blocks. Then it takes the 1st byte after the last matching block, appends it to non-matching data, and proceeds to compute A<sub>7-11</sub> checksum. After two more 2's are appended to non-matching data, it computes A<sub>9-13</sub>, which matches B<sub>6-10</sub> checksum. At this point, it can send `222` to the receiver as inserted data, and skip block of 3's.